# can I get help to plot a grid to overlap values (represent their values by a colour ramp) to a coordinate plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, grid, coordinates

I have coordinate data points (around 50 000 points) along a line on the actual surface. And I have some other data which was taken along that line on the surface. a machine was going along the line and recording latitude, Longitude and a reading of the specific location. Lets say that the data is something related to the magnetic condition of that point on the surface. I need to plot these coordinates on a grid with X and Y axis and overlap the magnetic data on top of that. To represent the value of the magnetic data I want to use a colour ramp. I want a grid with coloured dots which represents the magnetic data by using a colour. An example of the output is as shown below in the image. how to plot this in python?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path_to_file ="C:/Users/23928352/Desktop/Data/Value.txt"

Data = np.loadtxt(path_to_file)

print(Data.head())
print(Data.shape)
print(Data.dtypes)

NORTH=Data[:,2]
EAST=Data[:,3]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(NORTH,EAST)
plt.grid()
plt.show()

fig, ax=plt.subplots()

X= 'NORTH'
Y= 'EAST'

ax.plot('X,Y')
```

the grid was developed using this code
I want to continue with this because it is easier to plot the coordinates in a grid I want to super impose some other data which is in column 4 to this and represent the values using a colour ramp

Comment: What does the current plot look like?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just because you have WAY MORE data points than pixels in a few screens, you are in the position of using the `scatter` method of an Axes.

`scatter` draws a point *P<sub>i</sub> ≡ (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)* for every couple of coordinates in vectors **x** and **y**, and (optionally) colors the points according to a third vector using a color map (that you call color ramp), that is specified using an optional argument `c=...` in the method call.

Here it is the code, I create a couple of vector of coordinates, a vector of "magnetic measurements" and I scatter plot using `x, y, c=mf`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1.43, 2022.4,48000)

y = x/9+300*np.sin(3.14*x/2000)
mf = np.sin(3.14*x/600)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=mf, s=5)

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. this was so helpful and I got the output by modifying your code.